# How do I decode a JSON object whose attributes are stored as values in another attribute called "properties?"

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I am pulling weather forecasts from the National Weather Service. I get a JSON object that looks roughly like this (for all intents and purposes):

```
{
  "properties":{
    "periods":[
      {
        "number":1,
        "name":"This Afternoon",
        "startTime":"2020-05-21T12:00:00-06:00",
        "endTime":"2020-05-21T18:00:00-06:00",
        "isDaytime":true,
        "temperature":58,
        "temperatureUnit":"F",
        "temperatureTrend":"falling",
        "windSpeed":"20 to 23 mph",
        "windDirection":"SW",
        "icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/rain,20",
        "shortForecast":"Slight Chance Light Rain",
        "detailedForecast":"A slight chance of rain. Partly sunny..."
      },
      {
        "number":2,
        "name":"Tonight",
        "startTime":"2020-05-21T18:00:00-06:00",
        "endTime":"2020-05-22T06:00:00-06:00",
        "isDaytime":false,
        "temperature":39,
        "temperatureUnit":"F",
        "temperatureTrend":"rising",
        "windSpeed":"7 to 20 mph",
        "windDirection":"S",
        "icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/rain,50/rain,80",
        "shortForecast":"Rain",
        "detailedForecast":"Rain. Mostly cloudy..."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have defined a Swift struct to store the forecasts:

```
struct WeatherForecast {
    var startTime : Date?
    var endTime : Date?
    var temperature : Int? // Degrees Fahrenheit.
    var temperatureTrend : String?
    var windSpeed : String? // Miles per hour
    var windDirection : String?
    var shortForecast : String?
    var detailedForecast : String?
    var iconPath : String?
}
```

How do I decode the "periods" part so that I can get an array of WeatherForecasts (a.k.a, a [WeatherForecast])?

Comment: The simplest way is to define decodable data types up the chain: one that hold the `properties` key and another for the `periods` key, e.g. `struct Period: Decodable { let periods: [WeatherForecast] }`. Don't forget to make `WeatherForecast` decodable

Comment: @NewDev I made a mistake - there should be only one "periods" attribute, its value is an array.

Comment: Ok - I edited your question to fix. But what I said still stands

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to decode your data into a `Codable` `Properties` struct and then add a new initializer for `WeatherForecast` which accepts `Period` as a parameter and set the properties of `WeatherForecast`. And finally after decoding the data you could map it into the required `weatherForecasts` array.

```swift
let properties = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Properties.self, from: data)
let weatherForecasts = properties.properties.periods.map { WeatherForecast(period: $0) }

extension WeatherForecast {
    init(period: Period) {
        startTime = period.startTime
        // ...
```

Comment: The JSON object also has a bunch of data I don't care about. Does my Properties struct have to store the info I don't need, too, or can it just store the info I actually need?

Comment: You only need to have the data that you need. Rest you can avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define all the data types that map neatly to this JSON:

```
struct WeatherProperties: Decodable {
  let periods: [WeatherForecast]
}

struct WeatherData: Decodable {
  let properties: WeatherProperties
}
```

Then you can decode `WeatherData` and get to `[WeatherForecast]`:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let weatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, jsonData)

let weatherForecasts = weatherData.properties.periods
```

Don't forget to make your `WeatherForecast` conform to `Decodable`. If all the properties are Decodable too, there's nothing else you need to do other than declaring that it conforms:

```
extension WeatherForecast: Decodable { }
```